# Passing parameters into model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 3.0.3
ruby 1.9.2p0

The Problem:

I have a Users table which has many items, the item(s) in turn therefore belongs to the Users.

In my model item.rb i attempt to save the item along with the value for the user.id so i have:

```
self.User_ID = @user.id
```

this however give me the error

```
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

this is causing some confusion that it can't find this as in the show.html.erb that 'wraps' this page <%= @user.id %>  displays the correct ID on the page

Many thanks in advance

** EDIT **
The Shorten action is the action upon which i want to parameter to be passed

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def redirect
    @item = Item.find_by_shortened(params[:shortened])
    if @item
      #redirect_to @item.original
      redirect_to @item.original
    else
      redirect_to :shorten
    end
  end

  def shorten
    @host = request.host_with_port
    @user = current_user
```

Comment: Is the @user.id being passed back to the controller?  Looks like @user in your code has no value at the time .id is being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the `@user` model in every action that will require access to it. Having it render properly in the `show` action will not guarantee it is loaded in the `update` action.

Usually you need to have something like this in your controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_user, :except => [ :index, :new, :create ]

  # ...

protected
  def load_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id] || params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    render(:text => 'Record not found')
  end
end
```

Comment: I would not rescue the the exception. Let it raise. It will render the `public/404.html` page automatically.

Comment: Apologies, but i am pretty new to this and really struggling to see what is going on here.  I have tried the code in my users controller and it does not work, but i'm not even sure what it is meant to do, sorry.  Mostly my confusion is as to why this is in the users controller - should my work not be focused on the items controller?

Comment: The first part of this answer was the answer i needed - it was the ;new' action that i needed to amend - still not sure what the second bit was for but many thanks.

Comment: The reason you rescue the exception is so you can render precisely what you want. Dumping the user on a 404.html page will leave them without context on what's missing, and will not use the proper layout with any relevant session information.